How did the INC determine that Wayanad was a "safe seat" for Rahul Gandhi?
In the 2014 Indian Lok Sabha election, the Indian National Congress (INC) party was defeated badly; and their hopes in the 2019 national elections were not too high either. They were concerned about Rahul Gandhi, the Party Leader, losing from Amethi (Uttar Pradesh), his usual constituency. So in the 2019 election he also chose to contest from the Wayanad (Kerala) Lok Sabha constituency as it was considered a "safe seat" where his victory would be assured.
(In hindsight, this was a smart move by the party as Rahul Gandhi did lose in Amethi, but won big in Wayanad in 2019 even though the overall electoral performance of his party in 2019 was very poor nationally).
I was looking at the Wayanad Lok Sabha constituency wikipedia page, and it seems that in the 2014 national election the INC won there by just over 2% margin. In 2019, Kerala had a communist coalition government, who (later on) again defeated the INC coalition in the Kerala State Legislative Assembly election in 2021.
Given all these factors, why was the Wayanad constituency considered a "safe seat" in 2019 by the INC, for its leader Rahul Gandhi?

Re. VTC, we've had similar questions about picking safe seats before.  This one looks a bit obscure, but is really no different because it concerns Gandhi rather than Farage.  Unless one holds that India is just inherently less interesting than the UK.

@whosit - The "accusation" is a defense of the question against closure votes from other users (Re: VTC) by pointing out that it is similar to previous questions that have remained open.

@Obie2.0 Pretty much.  I'll vote to reopen if closed.  Like I said, exact same question - different person so not a dupe - on the UK, no problem.  But a question outside of the US (7500 Q) or the UK (1600 Q) quickly gets turfed out if it's "not significant enough".

"It is weird that..." Not really. Individuals make errors. The systems runs on consensus. After a few days when all the votes are in/possibly after a few close/reopen cycles, the question will be in a state that most people want it in. The influence of a single user is limited.

Do you have evidence that it was considered a safe seat? Might there be another reason for him standing there?

A sure win wasn't the only reason that Rahul Gandhi chose to contest from Wayanad (Kerala). It was part of a larger electoral strategy of the Indian National Congress (INC) to improve the party's prospective in South India.
The Wayanad Lok Sabha constitutency in Kerala was carved out of three districts - Wayanad, Mallapuram and Kozhikode. Historically, these districts (and neighbouring ones) have been a stronghold of the UDF coalition (lead by the Indian National Congress) in Kerala.

The Indian Express: Seven Assembly seats constitute the Wayanad Lok Sabha constituency ... In 2011, the Congress and its allies won all the seven segments in Wayanad, but fell to three in 2016 before climbing to four in 2021. From 1977 to 2004, before Wayanad was created by way of delimitation, the Lok Sabha seat was split across three constituencies – Calicut, Cannanore and Manjeri. In the nine elections held in that period, the Congress won Calicut and Cannanore six times each, but never won Manjeri. The Left parties won Calicut and Manjeri just once, and Cannanore three times. The IUML won Manjeri in every other poll.

(Note: the IUML is a coalition partner of the INC in Kerala).
Strong grassroot presence and a stable alliance with other parties is why the Congress has been winning from Wayanad, since 2008.
Regarding the drop in the margin of victory in 2014, that only happened because of the infighting within the UDF and within the Congress party in Kerala. Rahul Gandhi's candidature eliminated the bickering both within the party and the UDF coalition.

Business Standard: Its common knowledge that in the past there has been friction between the Congress and the IUML, especially in the northern districts, and it's more evident during the time of local bodies election ... He said one reason why the margin of Shanawaz had gone down in the 2014 Lok Sabha polls is that ... P.V. Anvar ... a former Congress leader contested as a Congress rebel in 2014 and he took away over 37,000 votes and the Welfare Party of India secured 12,000 votes ... This time the Welfare Party of India has pledged its full support to the Congress-led UDF.

A major factor why the Congress consistently wins in Wayanad is the demography of the region - Scheduled Castes, Scheduled Tribes, Muslims and Christians make up more than 50% of the voter base here. These minority groups have always been attracted to the Congress ideology of democracy, secularism, inclusive growth and social justice and make up their core voter base in Wayanad. (That is why the main rival of the Congress here are the left parties, who also practice secular politics and advocate for political equality and socialism).
Moreover, there is the geographical factor - the Indian National Congress is a major political force in the state of Kerala and Karnataka. The DMK party that won the state election in Tamil Nadu is also a member of the INC lead national coalition. As Wayanad is located in the borders of these 3 states - Kerala, Tamil Nadu and Karnataka - it also help to consolidate votes for the party during national elections.
But the biggest political factor is Rahul Gandhi himself - he is one of the very few north-indian politicians who is well liked, respected and quite popular in South India, today. Rahul Gandhi's candidature also resulted in a split in the opposition LDF coalition, with the Communist Party of India - Marxist deciding not to fight against Rahul Gandhi, considerably weakening the chances of the Communist Party of India candidate in Wayanad.
While the Wayanad constituency is a "safe seat" for the Congress, it is quite doubtful if other non-Keralite Congress leaders could retain the seat or even poll in as much votes as Rahul Gandhi (or Priyanka Gandhi) did. This is quite apparent when you consider the votes polled, and the huge margin of victory, when Rahul Gandhi was the candidate in Wayanad (Kerala) in both 2019 and 2024:

Data - Electoral Performance of INC in  Wayanad Lok Sabha Constituency (2009 - 2024)



Election Year (Candidate)
Votes Polled (%)
Margin of Victory (%)




2009 (Shanavas)
49.86
18.63


2014 (Shanavas)
41.21
2.80


2019 (Rahul Gandhi)
64.94
39.69


2024 (Rahul Gandhi)
59.69
33.59


2024 (Priyanka Gandhi)
64.99
42.90




It is a more interesting tale than Farage's support amongst the fish n chips crowd. What was the 2019 win margin, just to put that in perspective to the 2014's 2%?
